# Activity context

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have a question that bothers me, which I seem to find no answer on Google.
I created a small testing app with a piece of code that does something like this:

in `MainActivity`, I create an instance of `SomeClass` which has a method that uses a `context` as a parameter.
Inside this method [lets say it is declared like this: `public void doSomething(Context context)` ], I have a `Runnable` that runs after a couple of seconds (I tested with 5 seconds), that uses this context to get a `SharedPrefs` and put some value in it.

Now, after creating this object in `MainActivity`, and calling this method, I finish it, but in the Logs I can see that the context of the closed `Activity` is **not null**, and all that methods content runs successfully. 
My question is: If I close an `Activity` and after that, use it's context to do something with it, why doesn't it backfire with some sort of `Exception` or did I test it the wrong way?

Comment: Context is an interface to global information about an application environment. It is not Activity bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You killed the activity not the application,So it picks up the application context.And hence it is not null.

**A similar example**

A broadcast in fact has access to context but broadcast is not an activity.This is because of the same fact that it has the context provided by the application.

**Update**

For the last question in your first comment here's an answer : 
Few applications are cached by the system and this can be seen in the ***settings > Applications > cached processes(ice cream sandwich) .***
As said at sometime it may be cached and hence even after killing the only activity might not actually kill the application context.

i hope it helps you.

Comment: You are right, I just assumed that once I stop an Activity everything "connected" would simply go off. But as you said in the first line, if the Activity I stopped is the only one keeping the Application alive, wouldn't then make that code not run? But it still does.

Comment: So does that call for an upvote and correct answer ? :D

Comment: I'd just like you to answer this one more question I wrote. Better said, what would be a good example of null context, w/o directly assigning a null value to it?

Comment: For your last question : while you are within an application the context can't be null . As by default the framework provides the context. I hope all questions are answered now .